# Структура Django проекта и проблема с импортами

Tags: python, django, импорт, python-import

Я использую следующую структуру проекта. Проект для меня - это все то, что видит PyCharm. Т.е. проект это не только `django startproject` но и всевозможные файлы документации, конфиги `docker-compose` и т.п. Выглядит это так:

```
. (Папка проекта PyCharm)
├── env
├── site_proj (Сам проект Django)
│   ├── chat_app
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── templates
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── consumers.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── routing.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── site_proj
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── routing.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   └── manage.py
├── docker-compose.yml
└── README.md
```

Т.е. все, что касается Django проекта лежит в `site_proj` и не мешается с файлами, которые не относятся к Django.

Отсюда возникают проблемы с импортом:

1)

```
# ./site_proj/site_proj/routing.py
from ..site_proj import chat_app
```

`ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

2)

```
# ./site_proj/site_proj/routing.py
from site_proj import chat_app #  PyCharm autocomplete
```

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'site_proj.routing'`

IDE:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3)

```
# ./site_proj/site_proj/routing.py
from site_proj.chat_app import routing
```

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'site_proj.routing'`

Если корневой папкой для IDE будет папка Django проекта, то все будет ок, но я так не хочу. В чем проблема и как ее решить?

Comment: У меня есть подозрение, что текст ошибки ImproperlyConfigured приведён не целиком

Comment: Не знаю что там с PyCharm, но судя по структуре обычное `import chat_app` должно нормально работать

Comment: @andreymal да, как оказалось работает. IDE ругается, красит красным, но работает. Осталось с IDE разобраться... Не знаете в чем тут может быть проблема?

Comment: @IvanBlohin  Решил проблему? У меня, вдруг такая же ошибка. Python видит пути, а пичарм нет, подчёркивает красным.